# Ruby Sinatra Cookies

Tags: ruby

I am having an issue with setting persistent cookies in Sinatra:

I have two routes that set the same key:

```
response.set_cookie('user_id',
                    { :value => params[:user_id], 
                      :expires => Time.now + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), 
                      :path => '/'  })
```

The only difference between the two routes is that one is a POST and the other is a GET. In both cases I set the path of the cookies to '/'.

When I try to retrieve the cookie value in another route:

```
user_id = cookies[:user_id]
```

I always get the cookie that I set via the POST route, even if I later overwrite it using the GET route.

I haven't been able to find good documentation for this aspect of Sinatra, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
user_id = request.cookies[:user_id]
```